# Change background of entire website

Tags: joomla-2.5

please visit this link : http://naadiastrology.info/

I want to change the background for the entire website.

NOw you can see some lines in the background.

Is that lines are images? or what?

And i want to put background-color for entire website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS for your background is being pushed to the `<head>` of your template, most likely by Joomla's `addStyleDeclaration` function.

```
body.site {
    background-color: green;
    background-image: url("/templates/corpoboost/images/patterns/1.png");
    border-top: 3px solid #db8000;
}
```

In this case, it's most likely being set in your template parameters.

Go to **Extensions** >> **Template Manager**

Then select your template and there should be some options

Comment: hi, 

thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped :)